# Is it possible to know when a property is deleted?

Tags: javascript, node.js

```
var o = { a: 1 };
delete o.a;
```

I want to be notified when the property is deleted, similar to the getter and setter accessor descriptors.

Is it possible?

Comment: I don´t get it. It is deleted at that point in code where `delete o.a` is. So you know when and where you delete stuff.

Comment: No. Javascript does not have such a mechanism.

Comment: @Amberlamps Is not that simple. Using the same rule, I know when `o.a = 1` and `o.a` are executed but I can configure getters and setters. I'd like to have another function similar to the getters and setters that is executed when `o.a` is deleted.

Comment: I was about to say that there is the non-standard Mozilla `Object.watch()`, but even that wouldn't allow for a notification on a `delete`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @MarkGraham I've found the specifications for the Object.observe() specification proposal for the javascript harmony.

http://wiki.ecmascript.org/doku.php?id=harmony:observe

But this is not implemented in node.js (after a quick search).

I also found [Proxies](http://soft.vub.ac.be/~tvcutsem/proxies/), a more powerful way to intercept operations. It's also from the Harmony but in node.js can be enabled using the --harmony-proxies flag or --harmony to enable all harmony features.

Edit: Node.js implements an older version of the harmony proxies. This is the latest one: [direct proxies](http://wiki.ecmascript.org/doku.php?id=harmony%3adirect_proxies) and the example they provide doesn't work as expected. [google groups](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/nodejs/LPD8ut33-hg)

Comment: I don't think you wanted `Object.observe` with its *Asynchronous notification* anyway. Proxies will be the way to go.

Comment: You can't always use a proxy as sometimes you want to observe an underlying object that you don't have control over, eg a third party API

Answer (score 1):

If you can control your environment and ensure it's up to date then great.  This article about Object.observer will help.

http://updates.html5rocks.com/2012/11/Respond-to-change-with-Object-observe

Failing that, if you're catering for older browsers, then you'll probably have to write it yourself.  Always have performance in the back of your mind.  New browsers implement 'Worker threads' and presumably this is what Object.observe will be resourcing.

You would have to use a timer, but just "one", not multiple...  John Resig (Mr jQuery) has written various articles about timers and how they execute on a single thread.  Here's one of them:

http://ejohn.org/blog/how-javascript-timers-work/

Note.  I haven't tried this myself, so don't know if the performance will be acceptable.

Comment: My apologies.  That would have been clearer if Node.js had been mentioned in the title, as I didn't get here via the 'Tags' menu.

Answer (score 0):

There is no built-in "notification" system for these things in js. 
But I think the (simplest) solution is : call a method with your delete management code ( like you would have done with notifications) after deletion of the property.